# Best way for clustering strings using python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I have 3200000 strings  (all possible combinations of an alphabet = 'ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTVWY').
A small example of the data:

```
['AAAAA', 'AAAAC', 'AAAAD', 'AAAAE', 'AAAAF', 'AAAAG', 'AAAAH',
 'AAAAI', 'AAAAK', 'AAAAL', 'AAAAM', 'AAAAN', 'AAAAP', 'AAAAQ',
 'AAAAR', 'AAAAS', 'AAAAT', 'AAAAV', 'AAAAW', 'AAAAY', 'AAACA',
 'AAACC', 'AAACD', 'AAACE', 'AAACF', 'AAACG', 'AAACH', 'AAACI',
 'AAACK', 'AAACL', 'AAACM', 'AAACN', 'AAACP', 'AAACQ', 'AAACR',
 'AAACS', 'AAACT', 'AAACV', 'AAACW', 'AAACY'...]
```

I use this code to construct the big list of small strings.

```
def get_all_possible_kmers(alphabet, k):
    return [''.join(char) for char in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=k)]
```

My intentions are to cluster all strings in groups of shared/similar character compostions, i.e. those that are permutations of a single string. there would have different groups like: a1b1c1d1e1 , a1b1c1d2 , a1b2c2 .... a5 . Each cluster would have to include compositions as a1b4, b1a4, a1c4 , etc. 
So, each cluster would include all strings that are permutations of a given string composition, e.g. abbbb, babbb, etc.
There are any python tool I can use to make this kind of clustering?
I was thinking using some kind of distance metric like hamming distance or levenshtein distance.

Do you guys have any direction that would be appropriate for start?

Thank you by your time and knowledge.

Paulo

Comment: what do you mean by "where a-e stand for any, but different char from each other"

Comment: Man zet it means that each character is different from each other in some cases...ups I lost some part of the text. I will edit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to generate a cluster hash and update a set in a dictionary.

For example:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

clusters = defaultdict(set)
for item in get_all_possible_kmers(alphabet, k):
    clusters[str(Counter(item))].add(item)
```

You can also format the `str(Counter(item))` to look like you need (`a1b4`...)

Also, you can simplify the calculation by updating the clusters when you get the next kmer.

Comment: Interesting Yann. Thank  you